# difference between wavelet filters

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis

Some may think this question is little primarily,I just want to know the differences between different wavelet filters like decomposition high pass,low pass,reconstruction high pass,low pass filters..Which one is best suited for an ECG type signal

Comment: The best tool in signal processing does not only depend on the type of signal, but also the kind of objective you have. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to make a transform/ sparsifying matrix for Compressed sensing application typically for ECG reconstruction

Answer (score 1):

[Comparative Analysis of Wavelet Basis Functions for ECG Signal Compression through Compressive Sensing,](http://www.ijcst.org/Volume3/Issue5/p5_3_5.pdf) 2012 provides a comparative analysis for different wavelets. On a more generic basis, [Compressed Sensing for Bioelectric Signals: A Review](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28659/difference-between-wavelet-filters?noredirect=1#comment53584_28659), 2015, addresses other kinds on splines, Gabor wavelets, etc. The references therein could provide you with a good starting point.

[Fixed percentage of wavelet coefficients to be zeroed for ECG ccompression](http://dx.doi.org/10.1049/el:20030560), 2003, could be interesting as well, but I cannot access the paper.

Comment: ok,but the problem is that how they didnt mention how they have made these matrices,I mean transform matrixes